# Carrying 10 liter dewar in elevator advisable?

Tags: gas, chemical-compounds, laboratory-safety

I am using liquid nitrogen a lot at university and frequently have to carry a 10 l dewar from the storage container into my lab. On this way I have to walk down 4 stories with the heavy dewar. Carrying gases and chemicals in elevators is strictly forbidden, which of course makes sense, since the elevator can always get stuck and then you would be stuck with those substances, posing fatal hazard in some cases.

Now I'm asking myself if a 10 l dewar would not infact be completely irrelevant in this regard. Large gas flasks are out of the question of course, but can the content of a 10 l dewar pose any real suffocation threat? The elevator I'm talking about can comfortably fit 8 people.

Side note: There is of course an elevator dedicated only to chemicals but it would mean quite a detour for me.

Comment: Does your lab/facility not have protocols set in place for this?

Comment: @N.Steinle Basically the question is: "I know this is strictly forbidden, should I still do it."  This shouldn't be supported.  (Not to mention the homework aspect of it.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I can see how you may interpret the question as such, but I interpret it as, "why shouldn't I?" Which is a perfectly reasonable question - we should understand **why** we do and dont do what we do and dont do. And we should definitely not discourage people from questioning rules

Comment: @N.Steinle Well, then I'd still argue that this is homework, unless the OP did some calculations first to figure out the volume of 10l of liquid nitrogen.  And note that the question isn't "why".  It is "come on, will a small container really be dangerous"?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch That's surely fair enough, but the impression is not that the OP is trying to solve a HW problem - they didnt even include the tag. Rather, their curiosity seems to stem from using LN2 in practice

Comment: @N.Steinle In that case, I'd expect the OP to first do the basic calculation and then ask.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Fair enough, then perhaps I answered it too quickly! Apologies

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Phys.SE is not geared to provide safety recommendations.

Comment: @Qmechanic that seems odd, considering this https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2630/ question was well-received.

Comment: There is some name-calling which has been removed from this comment thread twice; knock it off. @N.Steinle, your linked question is from eight years ago. Our discussions about whether to tolerate safety questions are more recent, but not new: see [e.g.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6896/44126) and links therein. If you'd like the community to revisit that policy, the place to have that discussion is on [meta].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but can the content of a 10 l dewar pose any real suffocation threat?

IN practice, probably not because the dewar has a lid and assuming the elevator is working properly (its been serviced recently) then there shouldn't be any problem. But these are assumptions of circumstance and cannot be trusted.

IN principle, there are tremendous safety risks for bringing a bunch of liquid nitrogen into a confined container, i.e. the elevator. The biggest threat is that if the dewar's lid gets removed or broken (or something) and it spills, then the liquid nitrogen could displace enough oxygen from the elevator carriage to cause **suffocation** - big no no! Especially since you might not be the only one riding the elevator, and if you are the only one then if something bad did happen then who would know about it to help you?

So, in the world of insurance liabilities and accidents, it's best to use the stairs, or the elevator that is specifically designed to transport chemicals. If the dewar is heavy, then enlist the help of an aspiring undergraduate to help you carry it :)

EDIT: and to the point made in the comments, the [expansion ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_ratio) of liquid nitrogen is given here, so for every 1 liter of liquid nitrogen, in principle 696 liters of gaseous nitrogen can be produced (and liquid nitrogen turns into gaseous form at room temperature and atmo. pressure). So from this consideration, the risk is certainly non-insignificant.